# How to access a computer with TeamViewer while it's downloading?

Tags: networking, internet, remote-access, bandwidth, teamviewer

I'm working with two computers one is a PC in university and another is a laptop at home. I have installed **TeamViewr** on both of them to be able to control the PC in university from home.
I didn't have problems with it and I always connected very easily but two days ago when I was in university, I put about 40 files with a total volume of 30 Gigabytes in a queue in **Internet download Manager** of the PC and I set the queue to download the files **(and because of the low speed of internet in our country, it will take several days to get completed)**

From that day I can't access the PC from home and it's always shown as offline in **TeamViewer** of my tablet.
I have told my friends to go and see what's wrong with the connection and they say everything's OK

1. The PC is connected to the internet
2. TeamViewer is running on PC
3. Internet speed is rather fine
4. The download is being done normally

But I don't know why it is shown as offline in **TeamViewer**?
Just one of my friends says that he has had the similar problem a while ago and this is because all the internet traffic is allocated to download and doesn't let **TeamViewer** connect with a remote computer.
Now my question is
 1. Is this true?
 2. If yes, is there a special setting on either the computer or the
    TeamViewer to be able to control the PC remotely while it's
    downloading?

---

My friends have sent me a photo on telegram that shows TeamViewer is running on PC but it's not signed in.
I thought It may be the problem.
But they say there' no need to be signed in and I think they're right because this computer is our professor's and we haven't made a profile on TeamViewer's website with professor's Email.
They're right because I have always been connecting the PC without signing it in.
Just for the first time when I wanted to add the PC as a remote computer in my laptop's TeamViewer, I used its `UserID` and `Password`
[image]

Comment: Did they check that the TeamViewer on the uni PC has logged in? I mean, it can be running but without logging in into your session, you might not see it.

Comment: @Alfabravo I will update my question in a few minutes to let you about this aspect of the problem

Comment: @Alfabravo how can I prevent the session from being expired? I can log into my profile in both of the computers but for the remote computer how can I prevent the session from being expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the thing about seeing your TeamViewer associated PC as 'online' needs that TeamViewer is running AND logged in into your session. Otherwise, it will ***only*** have a random code to connect.

To keep it online, just tick the option "Keep me logged in". It should keep your session alive.

[image: Keep alive session]

Also check that it starts on boot and has your account configurated. Go to Extras

[image: Extras on main menu]

And check :
- "General" for TeamViewer to start at boot time.
- "Devices and contacts" (approximate translation, I have it in Spanish, sorry!) for your account details to be there.

[image]

[image: account settings]

Comment: so you mean I should set up unattended access in both computers and assign both of them to my personal team viewer account? But how I've been using the computer already? I have the other computer in my computers list in my laptop and each time I just double-clicked on it to connect?  I didn't need to enter password each time?

Comment: At least in your remote PC at uni, if you want to have a predictable access, adding it to your list of managed devices will do. Then you can login at home and get it from there.